# SwiftUI TextField axis pushing View down unexpectedly, even when lineLimit set

Tags: list, swiftui, textfield

I'm noticing some unexpected behavior when working with the SwiftUI TextField axis property in iOS 16. The code snippet below shows I have a TextField with a vertical axis set (I expect this should expand the text field to unlimited entry, scrolling down), and I've added a .lineLimit(5, reservesSpace: true) modifier to set the TextField's "box size" to 5 lines, but continue to scroll if I'm beyond 5 lines.

The image below shows the unexpected behavior.  Scrolling works as expected until I hit line 10 on an iPhone 14 Pro. Then, even though the TextField box remains the same size, it pushes down any elements below it in the List. You can see the "Completed" Toggle moving down slightly. It's also curious that the "push" happens not when I paste in a line, but when I backspace to type a new number - for example the third image shows the Completed area after I pasted in a new line (the 13th line, but starts saying "Line 10", and when I backspace over the "0" in "10" to write "13", that's when the "push" is triggered (it can be seen in the 4th image). This push will continue until the Views below the TextField are eventually pushed off screen (you can see this happening in the last image). Since I'm in a List, I can, of course, scroll to access the last items, but I hadn't expected the TextField to push items lower, even more so that it starts with Line 10 in a 5 line-limited TextField. Am I misunderstanding these Views and modifiers, or is there a bug in the implementation? Thanks for insight!

```
List {
    Group {
...
        Text("Notes:")
            .padding(.top)
        TextField("Notes", text: $notes, axis: .vertical)
            .lineLimit(5, reservesSpace: true)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        Toggle("Completed:", isOn: $isCompleted)
            .padding(.top)
    }
    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
}
.listStyle(.plain)
```

[image: 5 iPhone screenshots described above]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this approach will work, because `.textLimit()` modifier is used only for `Text()` view and not for `TextField()` as you are trying to do.